# Umbraco Getting Value from Content

Tags: umbraco, umbraco7

I've a little confusion over here, on this line of code

```
var cs = ApplicationContext.Current.Services.ContentService.GetById(1000);
cs.GetValue("test");

var nd = new Node(1000);
nd.GetProperty("test");
```

Both of that code can be used.. What is the different between that two code.. When and Why we use either one of them

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Umbraco Services**
The service layer of the new umbraco API introduced in umbraco 6 includes a ContentService, a MediaService, a DataTypeService, and a LocalizationService. Check out the [umbraco documentation](https://our.umbraco.org/documentation/reference/management/services/) for documentation on those services and the other umbraco services.

The services in umbraco hit the database and don't leverage all of the caching that umbraco provides. You should use these services sparingly. If you are trying to programatically add/update/delete from the database or if you are trying to get unpublished content from the database, you should use these services. If all you need is to query for published content, you should use the UmbracoHelper because it is much faster.

```
var cs = ApplicationContext.Current.Services.ContentService.GetById(1000);
cs.GetValue("test");
```

**UmbracoHelper**
The UmbracoHelper is what you should almost always be using when you want to query content from umbraco. It doesn't hit the database and is much faster than the umbraco services.

```
var node = Umbraco.TypedContent(1000);
var nodeVal = node.GetPropertyValue<string>("test");
```

If you find that you don't have access to the UmbracoHelper, you can make your own as long as you have an UmbracoContext:

```
var umbracoHelper = new UmbracoHelper(UmbracoContext.Current);
var node = Umbraco.TypedContent(1000);
var nodeVal = node.GetPropertyValue<string>("test");
```

**NodeFactory**
The NodeFactory is obsolete. If you are using Umbraco 6 or higher, I would highly recommend converting to the UmbracoHelper.

```
var nd = new Node(1000);
nd.GetProperty("test");
```

Answer (score 2):

In razor or frontend code, always use the UmbracoHelper

```
var node = Umbraco.TypedContent(1000);
var value = node.GetPropertyValue<string>("test");
```

This will query the cache for **published** nodes

You want to use the ContentService call to query the database, for example if you want information about unpublished nodes (you don't want to do this in your views)

Querying with the Node object is probably legacy (I've never used it)